# Instantiating child class multiple times based on same parent

Tags: python, oop, object, super, superclass

Let's say you want to build a deck of 52 playing cards. I have the following `Deck` class in Python:

```
class Deck(collections.deque):
    """Creates a deck of 52 playing cards"""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            map(
                Card,
                itertools.product(
                    Suit.__members__.values(), Value.__members__.values()
                ),
            )
        )
```

As seen, this inherits from `collections.deque` and relies on three other classes, namely `Card`, `Suit`, and `Value`. This works. However, now I would like to create another class named `Decks`, that contains *k* decks, depending on the user input. I just cannot figure out how to instantiate this class properly. What is a Pythonic way of instantiating `Decks` such that it either contains *k* `Deck` objects, or 52 * *k* `Card` objects?

edit: `Deck` contains several methods, such as `shuffle()` and `deal()`. I would like to access these methods from `Decks`, such that I can shuffle all *k* decks at once or deal one of the 52 * *k* cards without writing logic to deal with several isolated objects (dealing the 53rd card would need to deal the 1st card from deck 2, etc.).

Comment: `Decks` should probably simply be a list of `Deck` objects…?! `[Deck() for _ in range(42)]`

Comment: Thank you, that could be a way. Note that the `Deck` object has several methods, such as `shuffle()` and `deal()` (not shown as it somehow messes up the style). How would one access these? The output is now a list object.

Comment: You would access that on each individual `Deck` instance. `decks[0].shuffle()` etc.

Comment: Thank you, but in that case it would not be possible to shuffle `Decks`, only every individual `Deck` object. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes. What would it mean to "shuffle decks"? You can only shuffle each deck. If you want to shuffle *every* deck, you'll need to iterate through your list of decks and shuffle each one. If you want to shuffle your *list of decks*, i.e. bring your list of deck instances into a random order, then you shuffle that list. That would have nothing to do with `Deck.shuffle`. Of course you can implement that as a method on a hypothetical `Decks` class, which, again, would have nothing to do with `Deck`.

Comment: To shuffle a `Deck` object I am calling `random.shuffle(self)` on it. This shuffles the `collections.deque` object. I would like to also be able to call shuffle on `Decks`, such that it shuffles all `Deck` objects it contains. Similarly, `deal()` (which is just a `pop()` on `deque`) should deal from the complete stack, not from every individual `Deck` object. I believe I am following your answer. I just thought there would be an easy way to inherit these methods from `Deck`, whilst having multiple of these `Deck` objects in `Decks`.

Comment: Well, how exactly do you want to define `Decks`? Is it one big `Deck` with more cards, i.e. `[Card(), Card(), ...]`? You'd use that play one game which requires a lot of cards. Or is it a collection of independent `Deck` instances, i.e. `[Deck(), Deck(), ...]`? You'd use that to play several independent games, or one game that requires two separate decks for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your setup a bit, but with this simpler setup the code below should work. Hope it helps!

```
import collections
import itertools

class Deck(collections.deque):
    """Creates a deck of 52 playing cards"""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(
                itertools.product(
                    range(13), ['♧','♢','♥','♤']
            )
        )


class Decks(collections.deque):
  def __init__(self, decks):
    deck = Deck()
    for i in range(decks-1):
      deck.extend(Deck())
    super().__init__(
      deck
    )

decks = Decks(3)
print(len(decks))
>> 156
```